# Can the value of one wildcard let me choose a specific wildcard to use elsewhere in the rule?

Tags: snakemake

I think I want something like a dictionary structure relating my different lists of wildcards, and am not sure if this is possible or if so, how to specify it.

In the following simplified example, I have a 'main' wildcard, `opts`, and two secondary wildcards, `opt1_vals` and `opt2_vals`, that each pertain to one of the values of `opts`.
At the moment, I am running my pipeline with multiple similar rules, like below -- is it possible for me to combine them all into one?

```
opts = ['opt1', 'opt2']
opt1_vals = [0.1, 0.2]
opt2_vals = [0.01, 0.02]

my_rule1:
    input:
        "opt1/{opt1_vals}/input.txt"
    output:
        "opt1/{opt1_vals}/output.txt"
    run:
        "./my-script.py --input {input} --output {output}"

my_rule2:
    input:
        "opt2/{opt2_vals}/input.txt"
    output:
        "opt2/{opt2_vals}/output.txt"
    run:
        "./my-script.py --input {input} --output {output}"
```

Comment: What output files do you expect from the example you posted?

Comment: Adding to @dariober 's question: You have the same wildcards for the input and output of your rules, i.e. they are passed through. The `opt`, `opt1_vals` and `opt2_vals` are not in your example

Comment: Hello! I just corrected a small typo in the code above. I'm expecting four output files:
```
opt1/0.1/output.txt
opt1/0.2/output.txt
opt2/0.01/output.txt
opt2/0.02/output.txt

```
I guess another way to rephrase my question is that -- I want to use the values in `opts` as a wildcard, rather than defining separate rules for separate items in the list like I have here.

Comment: You can't have an unresolved wildcard, e.g. `opt2_vals` for an output of a rule. What you want can be done for the `input` of the rules, but `snakemake` always needs to know the output file names. If you know all `opts` and `optX_vals` beforehand you can also write an collecting rule running `my_rule` for all desired combinations.

Comment: @euronion "can be done for the `input`" -- Do you mean the [input functions](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/advanced.html#step-3-input-functions), or something else?

Comment: Yes, you can use an input function to use e.g. a wildcard `opt` to which then fills the values for your `input` either from `opt1_vals` or `opt2_vals`

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if this answers your question. Thanks for mentioning the desired output in your comment.

I assume you want a rule to loop over `opts` and their corresponding `vals`. For such a purpose, I think a dictionary helps here.

The code below

- produces `[opt1/0.1/output.txt, opt1/0.2/output.txt, opt2/0.01/output.txt, opt2/0.02/output.txt]`,
- assuming `[opt1/0.1/input.txt, opt1/0.2/input.txt, opt2/0.01/input.txt, opt2/0.02/input.txt]` exist.

```
vals = {
    'opt1': [0.1, 0.2],
    'opt2': [0.01, 0.02]
}

rule all:
    input:
        [f"{opt}/{opt_val}/output.txt" for opt, vals_list in vals.items() for opt_val in vals_list]

rule my_rule:
    input:
        "{opt}/{val}/input.txt"
    output:
        "{opt}/{val}/output.txt"
    run:
        "./my-script.py --input {input} --output {output}"
```

I think it could be done in one rule only (as the first rule is "just placeholder" specifying all desired outputs), but I don't know how to do it.

Technically, if you don't need to specifically know `{opt}` and `{val}`, you could put them into one as below. This has the advantage that it's more general -- `input.txt` can be in arbitrary deep dir structure. On the other hand, it makes it less obvious which cases it covers, so the former is probably better.

```
vals = {
    'opt1': [0.1, 0.2],
    'opt2': [0.01, 0.02]
}

rule all:
    input:
        [f"{opt}/{opt_val}/output.txt" for opt, vals_list in vals.items() for opt_val in vals_list]

rule my_rule:
    input:
        "{path}/input.txt"
    output:
        "{path}/output.txt"
    run:
        "./my-script.py --input {input} --output {output}"
```